# Python: What does the * mean in method arguments list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

See: [create method](https://github.com/tiangolo/full-stack-fastapi-postgresql/blob/490c554e23343eec0736b06e59b2108fdd057fdc/%7B%7Bcookiecutter.project_slug%7D%7D/backend/app/app/crud/base.py#L34)

```py
class ExampleClass():

    def example_method(self, a: str, *, b: str) -> str:
       .
       . 
       .
```

I am not sure what the * means inside of the method argument list.  Does this mean that there are more arguments in between `a` and `b`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A single `*` in the method/function definition makes the positional arguments, that are given to the right of the `*`, keyword-only arguments. That is, they are like keyword-arguments that are required.

If we simplify your example, we can see this further:

```
class ExampleClass:
    def example_method(self, a, *, b):
        return a, b

print(ExampleClass().example_method("First", b="Second"))
#Output: ('First', 'Second')
```

If we try to call the method using just positional arguments, the program crashes:

```
print(ExampleClass().example_method("First", "Second"))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\test4.py", line 5, in <module>
    print(ExampleClass().example_method("First", "Second"))
TypeError: example_method() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

We can also still use optional keyword-arguments as well:

```
class ExampleClass:
    def example_method(self, a, *, b, c="c was not set"):
        return a, b, c

print(ExampleClass().example_method("First", b="Second"))
# Output: ('First', 'Second', 'c was not set')
```

Comment: Thanks so much, this definitely clears things up. That is good to know that you can still set default values for these arguments `c="c was not set"`.  The syntax is misleading a bit when you first come across it, but makes sense now! THX